# How to calculate and print first N Prime Numbers Using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote the following recursive code but the outcome is strange. Please Help to find the error in my C code.

For example if I take the value of `n` as `10` then the output should be `2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29`
but with to my code the output is `2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19`

Ahh! I tried for a long time but couldn't find the problem. Here is my recursive C code:

```
void primeNumbers (int n)
{
    if (n == 0)  
        return;

    static int i = 2;
    
    if (isPrime(i))      
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;                
        primeNumbers(n - 1);
    }
    else 
    {
        i++;
        primeNumbers(n);
    }
}
```

The function to check Number is Prime or not:

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    // edge case, not a base case
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;

    static int i = 2; 
    
    if (i > n / 2) 
        return true;
    
    if (n % i == 0) 
        return false;
    
    i++;
    return isPrime(n); // call again with i+1 value
}
```

Output:     [if N is 10]

```
2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

if I take the value of `n` as `10` then the output should be `2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29` but with to my code the output is `2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19`.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) Hint: don't use static variables. Thank me later.

Comment: `if (n \<= 1)` seems to be a typo. Please edit

Comment: The logic in `isPrime` is obviously wrong as `9` isn't a prime.

Comment: As indicated above, the use of `static` is your problem. (NB: using recursion here is really artificial -- it provides no benefit, only downsides)

Comment: Sometimes you say that your output is "2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19".  Sometimes you say that your output is "2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19" (which is wrong).  Please edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you use a `static` variable `i` for the divisor that never gets reset to `2` for the next number to test.

Here is an alternative recursive implementation of `isPrime`:

```
bool testPrime(int n, int div) {
    if (n / div < div)
        return true;
    else
    if (n % div == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return testPrime(n, div + 1);
}

bool isPrime(int n) {
    return n >= 2 && testPrime(n, 2);
}
```

The recursive function can be simplified as a single expression:

```
bool testPrime(int n, int div) {
    return (n / div < div) || (n % div != 0 && testPrime(n, div + 1));
}
```

The enumerating function is also incorrect for the same reason: `static` variable `i` is never reset to `2` so the function would only work once, and you call it recursively with `n - 1` after testing and printing `i` so it stops enumerating half way.

The same approach can be taken for `primeNumbers()` to convert a loop into recursive calls:

```
void printPrimes(int p, int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        if (isPrime(p)) {
            printf("%d ", p);
            printPrimes(p + 1, n - 1);
        } else {
            printPrimes(p + 1, n);
        }
    }
}

void primeNumbers(int n) {
    printPrimes(2, n);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but according to your primeNumbers( ) function in range of N prime numbers will be printed but i said to print N terms of prime numbers.     if n is 5 then-  2, 3, 5, 7, and 11.

Comment: @Rana: my bad, I misread that. Answer amended.